# Can I have a SSL certificate for a domain name that redirects?

Tags: dns, security-certificate, openssl

I have registered a domain name only for forwarding users to my original website.

`www.secondarydomain.example` -> `www.primarydomain.example`

I already have a SSL certificate for my primary domain.  The redirects for `http://www.secondarydomain.example` forward to `https://www.primarydomain.example`, the way that I expect.

But if the user goes to `https://www.secondarydomain.example`, it throws an error.  I'd like to get an SSL certificate and ensure that the HTTPS version of the secondary domain gets redirected to the primary domain as well.

My host for my primary domain doesn't allow me to add any more domains to my account. What can I do ?

Comment: You have hosting for your secondary domain.   Without hosting users would get a "host not found" error.   You have set up redirects.   That means that you have some host for that redirect.   I've edited your post to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. Either buy multi-domain certificate if it's close to the end of primary domain certificate, or buy the certificate for the secondary domain only.

> My host for my primary domain doesn't allow me to add any more domains to my account. What can I do ?

Anyway you have somewhere redirect configured from secondary to primary. If it is just redirect and doesn't allow you to add a certificate - you need another hosting for the secondary. The certificate should be added in the same or similar way like you did for the primary. Eventually, you can consider secondary as an empty website which contains nothing but redirect, and buy the cheapest hosting which allows you to add an certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming apache running on your host and with hosting for your secondarydomain.com.

In your `secondarydomain.example` root folder put the following code into a `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.primarydomain.example/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect all requests to your `secondarydomain.example` to your `primarydomain.example`

[Similar question with answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7578810/301760)

Comment: It sounds like they already have a rule like this in place.  The redirect is working but they are getting an error saying that the security certificate is invalid when they access the redirect domain over HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

It is essential that both domains (`secondarydomain.example` and `primarydomain.example`) are secured with an SSL certificate.

You should confirm which SSL certificate you have purchased.

If you have single domain SSL certificate you need to purchase another certificate for your secondary domain, in this case you need to manage two different certificates for both domains like order configuration, renewals, etc.

In another scenario, you can use multi-domain SSL to secure your both domains using a single certificate.